# Сложный поиск в массиве с помощью array_search

Tags: php

Нужно найти индекс элемента во вложенном массиве, где элементы строятся следующим образом:

```
массив = [
    индекс => [строка1, строка2]
]
```

Причем, искомая строка сверяется с элементом `строка1` этого массива. Подумалось, что можно передавать в качестве первого параметра следующую конструкцию: `[строка, '(.*)']`, где `(.*)` - любая строка. Почему не работает?

```
$arr = [
    '1' => ['a', '1'],
    '2' => ['b', '2']
];
echo array_search(['a', '(.*)'], $arr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo array_search(['a', '(.*)'], $arr);
```

Указанная конструкция ищет элемент со значением `['a', '(.*)']` в массиве `$arr`.

> Первый параметр $needle в [array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) - это значение для поиска.

Естественно такого значения в массиве `$arr` нет, поэтому результат `array_search` false.

Можете сказать подробней что именно из такого массива нужно найти?

```
$arr = [
    '1' => ['a', '1'],
    '2' => ['b', '2']
];
```

Если нужно найти индекс элемента 'b':

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        if (($i = array_search('b', $value)) !== false) {
            echo 'First index: ' . $index . PHP_EOL;
            echo 'Second index: ' . $i . PHP_EOL;
            var_dump($arr[$index][$i]); // искомый элемент
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: можно и через foreach сделать, просто подумал, что такой вариант с `array_search` был бы хорош, если бы удалось заставить его искать без учета второго элемента. В общем, требуется найти индекс элемента массива `$arr`, в котором первый элемент вложенного массива равен искомой строке, а второй не учитывался бы.

Comment: @4eloweck с `foreach` возможно будет работать кстати быстрее

Comment: Ну ладно тогда, спасибо. В общем, это не проблема, просто было интересно.

Comment: @4eloweck Можно через array_filter или array_map сделать.

Comment: @4eloweck На счёт быстрее или медление я бы не говорил так как операция с массивами и так довольно тяжёлая штука...

Comment: И тут явная ошибка в алгоритме по этому минус 1. `$i = (array_search('b', $value) !== false)` т.е. если не равно false то это true значит $i = true; от сюда `var_dump($arr[$index][$i]); // искомый элемент`  это не искомый элемент это нотайс о том что индекса нет.

Comment: @Naumov да, ошибка действительно была связанная с расположением скобок, поторопился. Исправил. Спасибо что заметили.

Comment: Ага ставлю плюс я тоже ошибся :D return array_search не отработает так как 0 тоже false

Answer (score 0):

```
 class SearchArray {

 private $param  = null;

 public function __construct($search) {
    $this->param = $search;
 }

  public function searchArray($a) {
     if(array_search($this->param,$a)!==false) {
        return true;
     }
  }
}

$math = array_filter($arr, array(new SearchArray('a'), 'searchArray'));
var_dump($math);
```

можно так попробывать.